# Java error: possible loss of precision

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I'm making a small Java program which encrypts any type of file. The way I'm doing it, is the following: I open the input file, read it in a byte array with the same size as that file, then do the encoding, and write the whole array to a .dat file called output.dat. To index the byte array, I'm using a variable of type int. The code:

```
        for(int i : arr) {
            if(i>0) {
                arr[i] = arr[i-1]^arr[i];
            }
        }
```

'arr' is a byte array with the same size as the input file.

The error I get: CodingEvent.java:42: error: possible loss of precision

arr[i] = arr[i-1]^arr[i];

(an arrow spots on the ^ operator)

required: byte

found: int

What's wrong? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of `byte ^ byte` is, counter-intuitively, `int`. Use a cast on the result of the expression when assigning it back to `arr[i]`:

```
arr[i] = (byte)(arr[i-1]^arr[i]);
```

This is because the operator is defined as doing a [*binary numeric promotion*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) on its operands, and so what it's really doing (in this case) is:

```
arr[i] = (int)arr[i-1]^(int)arr[i];
```

...which naturally results in `int`. Which is why we need the cast back.

Answer (score 1):

The operands of the `^` operators are first [converted to an `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) (it is called binary numeric promotion). So both `byte`s (`arr[i-1]` and `arr[i]`) are converted to an `int` and the result of the operation is an `int` too.

You need to cast the result back to a `byte` to assign it to `arr[i]`.

Comment: LOL! We both referred to binary numeric conversion. That is just too geeky.

Answer (score 0):

If arr[] is of type **byte[]** then that's the problem, when java does any binary operation with integers, it returns wither an **int** or **long** depending of the operators. In this case the result of **arr[i-1]^arr[i]** is an **int** that you're trying to store in a **byte**.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [JLS 15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22)

> When both operands of an operator &, ^, or | are of a **type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type**, binary numeric promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

And [JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> 1.If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> 2.Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> 1. If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> 2. Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> 3. Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> 4. **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

Hence the below expression is first converted to an `int` .

```
arr[i-1]^arr[i];
```

To cast it back to `byte` , use an explicit cast :

```
arr[i] = (byte)(arr[i-1]^arr[i]);
```